# How to match classes in jQuery and add a new class after

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the example below you can see that the 360015452235 class
 `<li class = "section-list list-group-item flex-fill 360015452235"><a href = "/hc/articles/360015452235" class = "section-link">Paper</a></li>`
can also be found in the navigation list
  `<li class = "section-list list-group-item flex-fill 360015452235"><a href = "/hc/articles/360015452235" class = "section-link">Paper</a></li>`

How can I compare the two lists (by that number class) and add an "active" class to the navigation list if the class in the navigation list (3600... class),matches one of the classes in the sidebar?

I have a navigation list that looks like this.

```
 <nav class = "section-container">
          <ul class = "section-Ulist list-group list-group-horizontal">
            <li class = "section-list list-group-item flex-fill 360015539835"><a href = "/hc/articles/360015539835" class = "section-link">Shoes</a></li>
             <li class = "section-list list-group-item flex-fill 360015533615"><a href = "/hc/articles/360015533615" class = "section-link">Boxes</a></li>
             <li class = "section-list list-group-item flex-fill 360015613375"><a href = "/hc/articles/360015613375" class = "section-link">Pens</a></li>
             <li class = "section-list list-group-item flex-fill 360015452235"><a href = "/hc/articles/360015452235" class = "section-link">Paper</a></li>
             <li class = "section-list list-group-item flex-fill 360015533195"><a href = "/hc/articles/360015533195" class = "section-link">Lock</a></li>
             <li class = "section-list list-group-item flex-fill 360015452175"><a href = "/hc/articles/360015452175" class = "section-link">Print</a></li>
          </ul>
         </nav>
```

And a sidebar that looks like this

```
<ul id="sidebar-artcl-list">
             <li class="360015452235" aid="360015452235">
                 <a href="/hc/en-us/articles/360015452235-Paper" class="sidenav-item current-article">Paper</a>
               </li>
             <li class="360015539955" aid="360015539955">
                 <a href="/hc/en-us/articles/360015539955-Men">Men</a>
               </li>
              <li class="360015539975" aid="360015539975">
                 <a href="/hc/en-us/articles/360015539975-Basic" class="sidenav-item ">Basic </a>
               </li>
           </ul>
```

Comment: Did you try anything on your own?

Comment: I have already answered but I subscribe to the comment above

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to add a class to the nav based on your sidebar selection.
Then, you should first get the element selected, get the class of its child. Once you have the class you should fetch the element active with that class and then just add a class to the child

I have created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmn9zspx/) that replicates what I have just explained.

```
let active_sidebar_element_class = $('#sidebar-artcl-list a.current-article').parent()[0].className

let nav_element = $('.section-container li.' + active_sidebar_element_class);
nav_element.children().addClass('active')
```